# jQuery: How to include a value of an ID into .value()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 1 value that i'm passing into a kendocombobox aka drop-down

```
$("#AllCounty").data('kendoComboBox').val("Some Value")
```

The above line works,beautifully, now I have the value here "Some value" ;

```
($("#FindCountry").val()).trigger("change");
```

how can i include the `($("#seachcountry").val()).trigger("change");` value into `.val("Some Value")`

right now I have  `$("#txtBaCountryRegion").data('kendoComboBox').val()($("#seachcountry").val()).trigger("change");`

**HERE IS THE SAMPLE CODE**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      .map_canvas { float: left; }
      form { width: 300px; float: left; }
      fieldset { width: 320px; margin-top: 20px}
      fieldset label { display: block; margin: 0.5em 0 0em; }
      fieldset input { width: 95%; }
   #examples a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#geocomplete { width: 200px}

.map_canvas { 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 400px; 
  margin: 10px 20px 10px 0;
}

#multiple li { 
  cursor: pointer; 
  text-decoration: underline; 
}
.pac-container {
            z-index: 10000 !important;
        }

            .pac-container:after {
                background-image: none !important;
                height: 0px;
            }
        .map_canvas {
            float: left;
            z-index: 10000 !important;
        }

        .pac-container {
            background-color: #FFF;
            z-index: 20;
            position: fixed;
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
        }

        .modal {
            z-index: 20;
        }

        .modal-backdrop {
            z-index: 10;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->



<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Google Search Map </h4><h6>(Map only shows after you reseize the browser page and back) nb: Don't forget to refresh input field's value</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
   
   <div class="form-group">
  <label for="usr">Search:</label>
 
 <input id="geocomplete" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="search for a company..." value="" />

  <br/>
  <form>
  <label>Country</label>
  
  <input id="seachcountry" class="form-control" name="country" type="text" value="">
  </form>
</div>

        <div class="map_canvas"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel Process</button>
          <button  type="button" id="done" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Copy to Page</button>
        
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h3></h3> <hr> <p></p>  <p></p>  <p></p>  <p></p>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xl" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Find Your City</button>
<div class="panel">
  <h4>Senario: we only have 1 country in the drop down but the form in the modal can generate 200s countries, how to get any of the 200s countries (value) in the dropdown</h4>
  <select class="form-control" id="AllCounty">
    <option>Finland</option>
 
  </select>
  <p></p>
  <label>INPUT TEST (works GREAT)</label>
  <input placeholder="I want this value into the drop down list" id="INPUTTEST" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
</div>

</body>

    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/geocomplete/1.7.0/jquery.geocomplete.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(function(){
        $("#geocomplete").geocomplete({

  map: ".map_canvas",
  details: "form",
  types: ["geocode", "establishment"],
  })
  .bind("geocode:result", function(event, result){
     var map = $("#geocomplete").geocomplete('map');
     google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
     map.setCenter(result.geometry.location);
  })
;
      });
    </script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#done').click(function () {
                var countryValue = $('#seachcountry');
                $("#AllCounty").val($("#seachcountry").val()).trigger("change");
                //TESTING AN IPUT FIELD
                $("#INPUTTEST").val($("#seachcountry").val()).trigger("change");

                //REAL TEST BELOW
                $("#AllCounty").data('kendoComboBox').val("Some Value")
                
            });
        });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**PLEASE COPY CODE TO AN HTML FILE TO USE GOOGLE PLACES**

Comment: can you show more of your code? need more context

Comment: ok, no problem.. typing it now

Comment: Hi  ewizard, I have updated the question with sample code

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if you are trying to set the selected option of a select tag or trying to add a new option to a select tag but here are both:

select option from input:

```
var countryValue = $('#seachcountry').val()
$("#AllCounty").val(countryValue)
```

add new option to the select:

```
var countryValue = $('#seachcountry').val()
var $optionElement = $('<option/>',{'value':countryValue }).append(countryValue)
$("#AllCounty").append($optionElement)
```

by the way you have to set the property "value" on each option tag, example:

```
<select class="form-control" id="AllCounty">
    <option value="Finland">Finland</option>
</select>
```